# Why does it generates an error saying "Invalid Parameter Value", When I pass an argument of DATE type to crystal reports?

Tags: c#, .net, date, types, crystal-reports

This code runs perfectly on my computer, but causes error on client's computer.

```
cr.SetParameterValue("fromDate", fromDatePicker.Value.Date);
cr.SetParameterValue("toDate", toDatePicker.Value.Date);
cr.SetParameterValue("todayRate", Common.GetTodayRate());
```

The Error is

```
Invalid Parameter value: exceeds the Min or Max or conflicts with existing value or edit mask
```

here, fromDate & toDate are of 'Date' type parameters. while todayRate is of 'Number' type Parameter.

Any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Well given the parameters have the same values, instant suspicion is something to do with a difference between their culture (date and number settings) and yours. CR isn't something I use, are the parameters typed on the CR side. If they were getting converted to strings that  would pretty much guarantee an error like this

Comment: A stack trace (this is an exception?) might tell you more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to culture-sensitive processing of parameter inputs from your application code to CR. CR is apparently badly designed when it comes to multi-lingual support in specific situations such is this one.

The solution, albeit ugly, is as follows.

For each `Date`, `Time` or `DateTime` parameter field that you have in your report, do the following:

1. Within CR designer, change the type of the parameter field to `String`.
2. Create a new formula field and set its value to one of the following:

   ```
   CDate({?ParamFieldName}) // Date
   CTime({?ParamFieldName}) // Time
   CDateTime({?ParamFieldName}) // DateTime
   ```

   depending on the original parameter field type, where `ParamFieldName` is the name of your parameter field.
3. In your application code, pass the parameter value in one of the following ways:

   ```
   // Date
   report.SetParameterValue(
       "ParamFieldName",
       DateTimeObject.ToShortDateString().TrimEnd('.'));

   // Time
   report.SetParameterValue(
       "ParamFieldName",
       DateTimeObject.ToShortTimeString());

   // DateTime
   report.SetParameterValue(
       "ParamFieldName",
       string.Format("{0} {1}",
           DateTimeObject.ToShortDateString().TrimEnd('.'),
           DateTimeObject.ToShortTimeString()));
   ```
4. Within CR designer, insert formula fields instead of parameter fields and format their display within CR designer.

This has been tested on several cultures.

The ending dot in date string is being trimmed because CR, for unknown reasons, cannot process the dot, even on cultures that have the dot at the end of the dates (ie. Serbian - `14.3.2015.`)